# extract start and end date with regex group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a service period mentioned as

```
MAY 01-15
```

and I need to extract start and end date as

```
group 1 : MAY 01
group 2 : MAY 15
```

is it possible???

Comment: In what language you are trying that?

Comment: java...but my framework permits only limited operation.I cant use much of core java

Comment: Could you provide your attempt to solve the problem in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

This Expression

```
@(Jan|Feb|May) (\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})@is
```

gives you the following Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => May 01-15
    [1] => May
    [2] => 01
    [3] => 15
)
```

You should expand the first parenthesis with all the months you need/want.

Comment: Then you need to break the string into particles and match these manually.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Java - String replaceAll() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm)? Assuming your input is like sample.

> String str = "MAY 01-15";

```
String start = str.replaceAll("-\\d+$", "");
System.out.println(start);
```

> MAY 01

```
String end = str.replaceAll("\\b\\d+-", "");
System.out.println(end);
```

> MAY 15

See [test at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/brN6hy); Regex [test at regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/w0xeg6) (click on "Java")

- `$` is the end [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `\d` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[0-9]`
- `+` [quantifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for 1 or more
- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Also see [SO regex faq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3110638)

---

If the sample is only a fragment, first extract the relevant part:

```
String full_str = "foo bar MAY 01-15 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur, adipisci velit";
String str = full_str.replaceAll("(?s)^.*?(\\b[A-Z]{3,}\\s+\\d{2}-\\d{2})(?!-).*", "$1");
```

[Explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rN6nP1/3) (top right)